# package to return a map of structs

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

I have created the logic to populate a map of structs and it is working as expected.
Now, I would like to move that functionality to a package. Like so

```
package returnperson
func Person() map[string]personstruct {
   //do stuff
   return people
}
```

I defined the personstruct in the body of the function Person, however, line 2 is throwing the following error:

> undefined:personstruct(2,1)

I've researched and I don't seem to find a way to correct the issue.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please add the code for main file where you are using the package returnperson for person struct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a few hints on extracting something to a package:

1. Only functions, variables and types with capital letters on package level are accessible from the "outside" (other packages or main)
2. A public function should only return types that are public as well

In your case you say `personstruct` is defined inside the function `Person`. That is not possible if you want it to be a return value of the function. You need to define it on package level. Also it should be exported since an exported function uses it.

Here a sample:

```
package returnperson

// PersonStruct defines ...
type PersonStruct struct {
    // fields
}

// Person does ...
func Person() map[string]PersonStruct {
    var people = map[string]PersonStruct{}
    //do stuff
    return people
}
```

-- edit --

I would further suggest to call the package itself `person` and make it about managing a person, meaning the main item in this package would be a struct called `Person`. `returnperson` is more of a function name.

The package could also be about a list of persons (slice/map). Then maybe you want to call it `personlist` and the main topic of the package would be managing a list of persons with the main struct maybe called `PersonList`.

Just some suggestions to think about...